# C++ _ULonglong variable undefined in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

The problem occurs at "_ULonglong". It returns an error stating it is undefined. Kinda stuck at this problem for some time now.

```
void clothes_adding(string type,string description,int quantity,string 
colour,string size,double price)
{

int location=0; //1= found the location for adding the clothes
number_Clothes=number_Clothes+1; //increase the number of item in the system 
by 1

//create a new template and putting all the data

newnode=new clothes();
newnode->id= "C00"+ to_string((_ULonglong)number_Clothes);
newnode->type=type;
newnode->description=description;
newnode->quantity=quantity;
newnode->colour=colour;
newnode->size=size;
newnode->price=price;
newnode->next=NULL;
newnode->back=NULL;
```

Included libraries such as "climits" and "windows.h", dint help solving the problem.

Comment: You could use `unsignewd long long` or `uint64_t`, but if you must https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230393.aspx

Comment: `_ULonglong` isn't anything guaranteed by the C++ Standard so you can't count on it. Stick to the regular types. Might I say, that's probably 64 bits. Does your database really need that many unique identifiers for clothes?

Comment: Incidentally, you could have removed almost all of that code and still shown the problem.